# How to force maximum count detection on + sign

Tags: regex

Regex question here!

Here are two kind of lines I can get:

```
a b c d COMMENT
a b c d vs e
```

I want to parse only the first line

Here is what I'd do:

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((v(?!s)|[^v]).+)$
```

This would cleanly parsed any of this kind of line, not finishing by `vs e`..... unless I have more than one space, like this:

```
a b c d  vs e
```

I am trying to find a way to specify that the `\s+` preceding the negative lookahead should mean "Take ALL of the possible spaces" instead of what it currently does

How would I write that in Regex?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `\s+` preceding the negative look ahead does mean "Take ALL of the possible spaces". The problem lies elsewhere.

When the regex engine parses reaches the last two spaces just before `vs` it reads them using `\s+`, then the regular expression tries to match `((v(?!s)|[^v]).+)`.

It tries the first alternative `v(?!s)` which of course fails, so it needs to try the other one `[^v]).+` but fails too because the current character is a `v`.

This forces the regex engine to backtrack and let the last `\s` match a single space only, now the engine re-tries to match space followed by `vs`, first it tries `v(?!s)` but fails because the current character is a space, then it tries `[^v]).+` again and now it succeeds because `[^v]` matches a space then `.+` takes care of the rest of the line.

To fix this you can use @p.s.w.g solution or you can prevent the regex from backtracking the spaces read by the last `\s+`.

If you are using Java then you can do it like this:

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s++((v(?!s)|[^v]).+)$
                                   ^^
                   Note the double ++, this makes + possessive and prevents backtracking
```

Or in most other regex flavors you can do it like this, even in Java:

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(?>\s+)((v(?!s)|[^v]).+)$
                                 ^^^
                 Notice the atomic group, this prevents backtracking
```

Comment: Perfect, the second regex works fine with my .NET app! I didn't know about this atomic group thing, I'll try to read more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second space matches the `[^v]` pattern inside the group. To prevent this, I'd recommend this pattern instead:

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((v(?!s)|(?!v)\S).+)$
```

This will ensure that no spaces are captured at the beginning of the group (it must start with a `\S` character).

Comment: Oh good idea as well. I often run into this kind of problem, glad to have some solutions now. Thank you!